# Count number of comments over multiple files, including multi-line comments

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that counts all comments in multiple files, including both single line (//) and multi-line (/* */) comments and prints out the total. So, the following file would return 4

```
// Foo

var text = "hello world";

/*
   Bar
*/

alert(text);
```

There's a requirement to include specific file types and exclude certain file types and folders, which I already have working in my code.

My current code is:

```
(   gci -include *.cs,*.aspx,*.js,*.css,*.master,*.html -exclude *.designer.cs,jquery* -recurse `
    | ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch '\\obj' } `
    | ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch '\\packages' } `
    | ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch '\\release' } `
    | ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch '\\debug' } `
    | ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch '\\plugin-.*' } `
    | select-string "^\s*//" `
).Count
```

How do I change this to get multi-line comments as well?

**UPDATE: My final solution (slightly more robust than what I was asking for) is as follows:**

```
$CodeFiles = Get-ChildItem -include *.cs,*.aspx,*.js,*.css,*.master,*.html -exclude *.designer.cs,jquery* -recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\(obj|packages|release|debug|plugin-.*)\\' }

$TotalFiles = $CodeFiles.Count

$IndividualResults = @()

$CommentLines = ($CodeFiles | ForEach-Object{ 
    #Get the comments via regex
    $Comments = ([regex]::matches(
        [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName), 
        '(?sm)^[ \t]*(//[^\n]*|/[*].*?[*]/)'
    ).Value -split '\r?\n') | Where-Object { $_.length -gt 0 }

    #Get the total lines
    $Total = ($_ | select-string .).Count
    #Add to the results table
    $IndividualResults += @{
        File = $_.FullName | Resolve-Path -Relative; 
        Comments = $Comments.Count;
        Code = ($Total - $Comments.Count)
        Total = $Total
    }
    Write-Output $Comments
}).Count

$TotalLines = ($CodeFiles | select-string .).Count

$TotalResults = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Files = $TotalFiles
    Code = $TotalLines - $CommentLines
    Comments = $CommentLines
    Total = $TotalLines
}

Write-Output (Get-Location)
Write-Output $IndividualResults | % { new-object PSObject -Property $_} | Format-Table File,Code,Comments,Total
Write-Output $TotalResults | Format-Table Files,Code,Comments,Total
```

Comment: What is the question? Aside from your code only counting the easy to evaluate single line comments, I don't see an attempt to get the multiline comments.

Comment: @LotPings Well that's my question. I don't know how to evaluate the multi-line comments...

Comment: BTW ignore case is the default with powershell comparison operators. As -match is RegEx based you couöd use an alternate instead of several where -> `|Where-Object FullName -notmatch "\\obj|\\packages|\\release|\\debug|\\plugin-"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear: Using string matching / regular expressions is not a fully robust way to detect comments in JavaScript / C# code, because there can be false positives (e.g., `var s = "/* hi */";`); for robust parsing you'd need a language parser.

If that is not a concern, and it is sufficient to detect comments (that start) on their own line, optionally preceded by whitespace, here's a concise solution (PSv3+):

```
(Get-ChildItem -include *.cs,*.aspx,*.js,*.css,*.master,*.html -exclude *.designer.cs,jquery* -recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\(obj|packages|release|debug|plugin-.*)' } |
    ForEach-Object { 
      [regex]::matches(
        [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName), 
        '(?sm)^[ \t]*(//[^\n]*|/[*].*?[*]/)'
      ).Value -split '\r?\n'
    }
 ).Count
```

With the sample input, the `ForEach-Object` command yields `4`.
Remove the `^[ \t]*` part to match comments starting anywhere on a line.

- The solution reads each input file *as a single string* with [`[IO.File]::ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_) and then uses the [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_) method to extract all (potentially line-spanning) comments.

  - Note: You could use `Get-Content -Raw` instead to read the file as a single string, but that is much slower, especially when processing multiple files.
  - The regex uses in-line options `s` and `m` (`(?sm)`) to respectively make `.` match newlines too and to make anchors `^` and `$` match line-individually.
  - `^[ \t]*` matches any mix of spaces and tabs, if any, at the start of a line.
  - `//[^\n]*$` matches a string that starts with `//` through the end of the line.
  - `/[*].*?[*]/` matches a block comment across multiple lines; note the *lazy* quantifier, `*?`, which ensures that very *next* instance of the closing `*/` delimiter is matched.
- The matched comments (`.Value`) are then split into individual lines (`-split '\r?\n'`), which are output.
- The resulting lines across all files are then counted (`.Count`)

---

As for what you tried:

The fundamental problem with your approach is that `Select-String` with file-info object input (such as provided by `Get-ChildItem`) invariably processes the input files *line by line*.

While this could be remedied by calling `Select-String` inside a `ForEach-Object` script block in which you pass each file's content *as a single string* to `Select-String`, direct use of the underlying regex .NET types, as shown above, is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

An IMO better approach is to count net code lines by removing single/multi line comments.

For a start a script that handles single files and returns for your above sample.cs the result `5`

```
((Get-Content sample.cs -raw) -replace "(?sm)^\s*\/\/.*?$" `
  -replace "(?sm)\/\*.*?\*\/.*`n" | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```

**EDIT: without removing empty lines, build the difference from total lines**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\31\SO_53092258.ps1

$Data = Get-ChildItem *.cs | ForEach-Object {
    $Content = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw
    $TotalLines = (Measure-Object -Input $Content -Line).Lines
    $CodeLines = ($Content -replace "(?sm)^\s*\/\/.*?$" `
          -replace "(?sm)\/\*.*?\*\/.*`n" | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
    $Comments = $TotalLines - $CodeLines
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        File    = $_.FullName
        Lines   = $TotalLines
        Comments= $Comments
    }
}

$Data
"="*40
"TotalLines={0} TotalCommentLines={1}" -f (
    $Data | Measure-Object -Property Lines,Comments -Sum).Sum
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\31\SO_53092258.ps1

File                          Lines Comments
----                          ----- --------
Q:\Test\2018\10\31\example.cs    10        5
Q:\Test\2018\10\31\sample.cs      9        4
============================================
TotalLines=19 TotalCommentLines=9
```

Comment: That's backwards from what I want to do. I need the number of comment lines, not the number of non-comment lines

Comment: I know, but sometimes you get further with a different point of view. See changed answer.